# Scheduled tasks (Timers) in Swing

Tags: java, swing

A GUI using Swing, must update part of its UI from a every 5 seconds. (`output.setPage(url)`)

The code is running in a timer, but on every update, the GUI hangs.

How do I avoid making the UI hang?

Here is my code:

```
<insert code here>
```

Comment: Post your code where `<insert code here>` is written.

Comment: You thanked trashgod for his answer because it worked for you. Don't forget to mark his answer as the accepted answer so your question is closed.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using a `setPage()` method of [`JEditorPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html), the event dispatch thread is blocked while the page is fetched. Using [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is a reasonable alternative.

Addendum: [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is convenient for showing progress; but as an alternative, you might look into the asynchronous feature of [`setPage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage%28java.net.URL%29) using [`setAsynchronousLoadPriority()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/AbstractDocument.html#setAsynchronousLoadPriority%28int%29).

Comment: @Double: Excellent. I prefer `SwingWorker`, but I also suggested an alternative above.